# How to bind function arguments

Tags: r, bind, apply

How do I partially bind/apply arguments to a function in R?

This is how far I got, then I realized that this approach doesn't work...

```
bind <- function(fun,...)
{
  argNames <- names(formals(fun))
  bindedArgs <- list(...)
  bindedNames <- names(bindedArgs)
  function(argNames[!argNames %in% bindedArgs])
   {
   #TODO
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Call function passed as `fun` with only it's formal arguments? If so, what if `fun` also has `...`?

Comment: how to find bunction arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried looking at roxygen's Curry function?

```
> library(roxygen) 
> Curry
function (FUN, ...) 
{
    .orig = list(...)
    function(...) do.call(FUN, c(.orig, list(...)))
}
<environment: namespace:roxygen>
```

Example usage:

```
> aplusb <- function(a,b) {
+   a + 2*b
+ }
> oneplusb <- Curry(aplusb,1)
> oneplusb(2)
[1] 5
```

**Edit:**
Curry is concisely defined to accept named or unnamed arguments, but partial application of `fun` to arguments by way of `formal()` assignment requires more sophisticated matching to emulate the same functionality. For instance:

```
> bind <- function(fun,...)
+ {
+   argNames <- names(formals(fun))
+   boundArgs <- list(...)
+   boundNames <- names(boundArgs)
+   if(is.null(boundNames)) {
+     formals(fun)[1:length(boundArgs)] <- boundArgs
+   } else {
+     formals(fun)[match(names(boundArgs),argNames)] <- boundArgs
+   }
+   fun
+ }
> oneplusb <- bind(aplusb,1)
> oneplusb(2)
Error in 2 * b : 'b' is missing
```

Because the first argument in this function is still `a`, you need to specify which argument `2` is intended for (`b=`), or pass it as the second argument.

```
> oneplusb
function (a = 1, b) 
{
    a + 2 * b
}
> oneplusb(b=2) ## or oneplusb(,2)
[1] 5
```

Comment: No I hadn't, thanks for the pointer.

`    function (FUN, ...) 
    {
      .orig = list(...)
      function(...) do.call(FUN, c(.orig, list(...)))
    }`

A really simple solution... however, this completely removes names from the resulting function... but I guess with that and above solution both cases could be covered.

Comment: Actually, you can still pass arguments by name to `Curry` -- try it out: `Curry(aplusb,b=2)(a=1)`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a version of Curry that both preserves lazy evaluation of function argument, but constructs a function that prints moderately nicely:

```
Curry <- function(FUN, ...) {
  args <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
  args$... <- as.name("...")

  env <- new.env(parent = parent.frame())

  if (is.name(FUN)) {
    fname <- FUN
  } else if (is.character(FUN)) {
    fname <- as.name(FUN)
  } else if (is.function(FUN)){
    fname <- as.name("FUN")
    env$FUN <- FUN
  } else {
    stop("FUN not function or name of function")
  }
  curry_call <- as.call(c(list(fname), args))

  f <- eval(call("function", as.pairlist(alist(... = )), curry_call))
  environment(f) <- env
  f
}
```

It basically works by generating an anonymous function in exactly the same way you would if you were constructing the partial binding yourself.

Comment: any chance to see this in plyr one day? it seems R-core doesn't like Curry, and roxygen is an inconvenient location.

Comment: No, but it might appear in a higher order functions package.

Comment: Also, the next version of roxygen won't have it.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, this seems to work as a work around

```
bind <- function(fun,...)
{
  boundArgs <- list(...)
  formals(fun)[names(boundArgs)] <- boundArgs
  fun
}
```

However, ideally I want the bound arguments to disappear completely from the new function so that calls to the new function can happen with name specification, e.g. with `add <- function(a,b) a+b` I would like `(bind(add,a=2))(1)` to return 3.

Comment: Right, this is better than my matching using formals.