# Is it possible to evaluate only some of the variables?

Tags: r

Is it possible to evaluate only some of the variables?

```
t<- function(a,b,c){a+b+c}
t(1,2,c)
```

which produces the error

> Error in a + b + c : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: What exactly are you expecting/hoping to happen?

Comment: I want to produce a single variable function from a multivariable function by evaluating all but one of the variables.

Comment: So in your example you would to make a function of c?  Would defining a new function be out of the question.  Something like `t2=function(c){t(1,2,c)}`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547219/r-project-how-to-bind-function-arguments

Answer (score 1):

You could set some defaults and that way you don't have to input all of the parameters.

```
fun <- function(a=0, b=0, c=0){return(a + b + c)}
fun(1, 2, 3)
#[1] 6
fun(4, 5)
#[1] 9
fun()
#[1] 0
```

Note that you probably shouldn't call a function 't' since there is already a fairly important function named t.

I'm guessing you're trying to work on a slightly more complicated example.  Otherwise you could just use sum to accomplish this task.

---

Edit:  It seems you just want to turn a multiparameter function into a single parameter function by setting the value for some of the parameters.  You can just define a new function that does what you want.

```
newfun <- function(c){return(fun(1, 2, c))}
newfun(1)
#[1] 4
newfun(5)
#[1] 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> t<- function(a,b,c){if(missing(c)) { function(c){a+b+c}} else{a+b+c} }
> t(1,2)(4)
[1] 7
> t(1,2)
function(c){a+b+c}
<environment: 0x159956028>
> t(1,2,3)
[1] 6
```