# setting formal arguments of 'foreach' function

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I am trying to set formal arguments of foreach function. I will give a simple example using .combine argument.

I wrote a general wrapper that change the formals of a function (code below)

```
bind<-function(FUN,args.new) {
    args.all<-formals(FUN)
    args.all[names(args.all) %in% names(args.new)]<-args.new
    FUN.tmp<-FUN
    formals(FUN.tmp)<-args.all
    FUN.tmp
}
```

So, I change the formals of foreach function

```
library(foreach)    
foreach.bind<-bind(foreach,list('.combine'='rbind'))
```

when I check the new formals I get (as expected):

```
> formals(foreach.bind)
$...


$.combine
[1] "rbind"

$.init


$.final
NULL

$.inorder
[1] TRUE

$.multicombine
[1] FALSE

$.maxcombine
if (.multicombine) 100 else 2

$.errorhandling
c("stop", "remove", "pass")

$.packages
NULL

$.export
NULL

$.noexport
NULL

$.verbose
[1] FALSE

>
```

but when I call foreach.bind everything works like .combine variable was not set! For example, declaring:

```
a<-function(x) c(1,x)
```

and calling:

```
> foreach.bind(i=list(1,2,3)) %do% a(i)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 3

>
```

as I said, like .combine parameter was not formally set.

On the other hand, if I call the original function it woks:

```
> foreach(i=list(1,2,3),.combine='rbind') %do% a(i)
         [,1] [,2]
result.1    1    1
result.2    1    2
result.3    1    3
>
```

Anyways, can anybody explain me what is happening in this case? or provide me with other ways to 'bind' foreach function?

Comment: I'm not sure what changing the formal parameter list does, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547219/how-to-bind-function-arguments describes how to do the thing you were trying to do.

Comment: I saw this post. That is exactly what my bind function does. As Steve said, it is a issue with the foreach function, which checks for missing values.

Comment: I was referring specifically to the `Curry` function (at the very top of the accepted answer), which does *not* do what your bind function does, and which seems far more likely to work correctly in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.combine` argument isn't given a default value in the `foreach` function.  Instead, `foreach` checks to see if the `.combine` argument is missing.  Your code provides a default value for `.combine`, but if you don't specify a value for it, it's still missing, and therefore the default combine behavior doesn't change.

One solution is to create a wrapper function that has the same formal arguments as `foreach` and then calls `foreach` by manipulating and then eval'ing a call object returned by `match.call`:

```
library(foreach)
foreach.bind <- function() {
    cobj <- match.call()
    cobj[[1]] <- as.name('foreach')
    nms <- names(cobj)
    if (! '.combine' %in%  nms) {
      cobj[[length(cobj) + 1]] <- 'rbind'
      names(cobj) <- c(nms, '.combine')
    }
    eval(cobj)
}
formals(foreach.bind) <- formals(foreach)
```

This modifies the default combine behavior while still allowing you to specify your own combine function:

```
> foreach.bind(i=1:3) %do% c(1,i)
         [,1] [,2]
result.1    1    1
result.2    1    2
result.3    1    3
> foreach.bind(i=1:3, .combine='c') %do% c(1,i)
[1] 1 1 1 2 1 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. UNfortunately, a nested function does not work in my case. I have to be more general than that...